# how to combine rows data of same id in one row

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

My controller function:

```
function index()
{
    $data['user_clicks'] = $this->common_model->get_userClicks();
    $this->load->view('common/header');
    $this->load->view('content_pages/user_clicks',$data);
    $this->load->view('common/footer'); 
}
```

My model

```
function get_userClicks()
{
    $this->db->select('agent_id,click_type,click_count');
    $this->db->select_sum('click_count');
    $this->db->from('daily_clicks');
    $this->db->group_by('click_type,agent_id');
    $this->db->order_by('agent_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

[image: this is i am getting, what i want is to get the click_count of phone click, email click,offline click with respect to their columns and their total clicks is already done]

[image: the database looks like this:]

this is i am getting, what i want is to get the click_count of phone click, email click,offline click with respect to their columns and their total clicks is already done.
the data base image is the last one klindly help me get through it.
Thank you

Comment: is what this line return $q->result_array(); returns an multidimensional array with each inner array containing a row of resulting table?

Comment: What you're looking for is `WITH ROLLUP`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html at least in straight SQL. Not sure if Code Igniter has that functionality.

Comment: @jefwa here i want to get the click counts with respect to their click type and manage that result according to my view (the first image).
if the click type is phone then the clickcount should be at the phone click column and same goes for every column.

Comment: post what this returns $q->result_array(); then only we can try to create a code

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan this returns an array that contains the row of resulting table

Comment: a single row of a resulting table?

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan no no multidimensional array that returns inner array containing row of resulting table.
like this:
array (size=1)
  'user_clicks' => 
    array (size=14)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'agent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'click_type' => string 'offline' (length=7)
          'click_count' => string '3783' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'agent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'click_type' => string 'phone' (length=5)
          'click_count' => string '3655' (length=4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$resarr=count($resultarray);
<table>
<tr>
<th>Agent_id</th>
<th>phone_click</th>
<th>email_click</th>
<th>offline_click</th>
<th>total_click</th>
</tr> 
for($i=1; $i<100; $i++){ //agent id
 for($j=1; $j<=$resarr; $j++) //number of records
 { 
   echo "<tr>";
   if($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['agent_id'] == $i)
   {
     if(!empty($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['agent_id']){
       echo "<td">
       echo $arr['user_clicks'][$j]['agent_id'];
       echo "</td>";  
     }

     if($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type']=='phone'){
       echo "<td">
       echo $arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type'];
       echo "</td>";  
     }
     else 
     {
       echo "<td">
       echo '';
       echo "</td>";  
     }

     if($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type']=='email'){
       echo "<td">
       echo $arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type'];
       echo "</td>";  
      }else 
      {
         echo "<td">
         echo '';
         echo "</td>";  
       }

       if($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type']=='offline'){
           echo "<td">
          echo $arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_type'];
          echo "</td>";  
        }
          else 
        {
        echo "<td">
         echo '';
        echo "</td>";  
         }

          if(!empty($arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_count']){
             echo "<td">
            echo $arr['user_clicks'][$j]['click_count'];
             echo "</td>";  
           }
           else 
          {
          echo "<td">
          echo '';
              echo "</td>";  
           }


     }
       echo "</tr>";  
   }
}
```